# Developing helper functions that generate HTML: should I rather use nested content_tag()s or partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-engines

I'm at the start of developing a Rails engine (and gem) that should provide many small helper functions that generate HTML for views.

Now I wonder whether it's advisable to rely on the use of many nested `content_tag` calls to generate the HTML, or if it's more pragmatic to just rely on partials.

In my opinion, the first approach may be a bit cleaner (but slower in performance), but the 2nd approach seems much easier to do, so I guess I will favor the 2nd one. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> many nested `content_tag` calls

does not sound as if you should be doing this in a helper. 1 or 2 levels of tags is my personal limit, above that I go for the partial.

Thats just my feeling, no theory involved here :-)

Comment: Thanks, I guess you're absolutely right. I posted a follow up question about this topic here [Rails: Refactoring HTML producing helper method to use a partial - how to use blocks there?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543025/rails-refactoring-html-producing-helper-method-to-use-a-partial-how-to-use-bl)