# Rails: Refactoring HTML producing helper method to use a partial - how to use blocks there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, helper

After my earlier question [Developing helper functions that generate HTML: should I rather use nested content_tag()s or partials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530692/developing-helper-functions-that-generate-html-should-i-rather-use-nested-conte/12530753#12530753) I am convinced now to rewrite some of my more complex HTML generating helper functions to use templates instead of nested `content_tag()` calls.

So here's my original helper:

```
def bootstrap_navlist(&block)
  classes = ['nav', 'nav-list']

  content_tag(:ul, class: classes.join(' ')) do
    capture(self, &block)
  end
end
```

And that's what I came up with using a partial now:

```
def bootstrap_navlist(&block)
  render partial: 'bootstrap/navlist'
end

# views/bootstrap/_navlist.html.erb
<ul class="<%= ['nav', 'nav-list'].join(' ') %>">
  How do I output the block here??
</ul>
```

The block looks something like this, but it can be any HTML you like:

```
= bootstrap_navlist do |navlist|
  = navlist.item 'Home', '#'
  = navlist.sublist 'Meine Favoriten', '/favorites' do |sublist|
```

As you can guess, I'm not sure how to output the block in the view. Should I simply capture it in the helper and pass it as a `:local` variable? Or is there a more common way?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Show the `&block` please

Comment: Added it to my question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where the content tags were not deeply nested an would be reasonable as a helper.

Your helper, and partial would look like this:

```
def bootstrap_navlist(&block)
  render template: 'bootstrap/navlist', :locals => { :block => block }
end


<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <%= capture(self, &block) %>
</ul>
```

Comment: It needs to be `render :template => ...`. And in the view, `capture(self, block)` results in `no block given`, so I guess it must bei `capture(self, &block)`. I updated your post accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't sure about block vs &block, and made a guess.  I took the render syntax from the question, but wouldn't that be partial: 'bootstrap/navlist' ?